# The SESSION of PHP can not save?

Tags: php

Different web browser, different platform can not share the same string variable,it starts from null.
I want a function like chat room.

note.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['note']=$_POST['text'].'<br>'.$_SESSION['note'];
?>
<html>
<body>
<title>Note</title>
<form method="post" action="note.php" name=form1>
<input type="text" name="text" size=150 required>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="B1">
<input type="reset" value="reset" name="B2">
</form>
<?php
echo $_SESSION['note'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

use file methord can save the variable.

```
<html>
<body>
<title>NoteF</title>
<form method="post" action="notef.php" name=form1>
<input type="text" name="text" size=100>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="B1">
<input type="reset" value="cancel" name="B2">
</form>
<?php
$file='notes.txt';
$fr='';
if(file_exists($file)){
 $fr=file_get_contents($file);
}
if($_POST['text']==''){
 echo $fr;
}else{
 $fw=$_POST['text'].'<br>'.$fr;
 $myfile = fopen($file, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
 fwrite($myfile, $fw);
 fclose($myfile);
 echo $fw;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But server(sinaapp.com) do not allowed :fopen(notes.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied.
But sinaapp.com supply memcache to save temporary variable,and no fee under 20MB.

```
<html>
<body>
<title>NoteMemCache</title>
<form method="post" action="notemc.php" name=form1>
<input type="text" name="text" size=100>
<input type="submit" value="提交" name="B1">
<input type="reset" value="取消" name="B2">
</form>
<?php
$mmc = memcache_connect();
$notes='';
if ($mmc == false) {
 echo "mc init failed\n";
} else {
 $notes=memcache_get($mmc, "notes");
 if($_POST['text']==''){
  echo $notes;
 }else{
  $newnotes=$_POST['text'].'<br>'.$notes;
  echo  $newnotes;
  memcache_set($mmc, "notes", $newnotes);
 }
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

DEMO:http://sonichy.sinaapp.com/notemc.php

Comment: Each client browser gets its own session. If you want to share data between clients, use a file or database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that sessions work is there is a session id that is sent as a cookie in the response from the server.  The browser then stores that id and sends that information back to the server with every subsequent request.  If you use another browser or even the same browser with a different profile then, that session id will be different.

The server uses that session id to look up all of the session variables stored for that request.  If you want to share data across multiple browsers then you will have to store that information in some form of permanent storage (a file or a database).

You will also need some unique identifier to link the 2 browsers.  Something like an account id (that is granted after registration and authentication).

As a basic example imagine you have a mysql database with a table like this:

id | chat_id | note
1  |   1     | Hello
2  |   1     | Good-bye

Then if your url is `note.php?chat_id=1` then you could grab chat_id from the url using `$chatId = $_GET['chat_id']` and query your database for all notes with chat_id.  Then any browser could go to that url and they would all see the same thing.

You need to gain a more basic knowledge of php before you develop this... I would find a tutorial before you get too far into it.

Comment: How to operate specific ?

Comment: See my notes... but you really do need to follow an online tutorial to learn more about php.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['text']))
    {
    $_SESSION['note']=$_POST['text'].'<br>'.$_SESSION['note'];
    }
```

However, the session ID will be different on different browsers

Answer (score 0):

this could be done using the session_id() function but would be very insecure since a malicious user could generate random session IDs and hijack the session. You would be better off storing this info in a database and creating a API to interact with your application.

A newer more cutting edge approach would be to use angularJS and socket.io. This would make a perfect chat room application.